# Sort a list of custom object with String contains in the object

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, object

I have a `list` contains custom `object Box`. I want to `sort` the list alphabetically with a `String`  property of the `object Box`.

I have tried `boxList.sort()`, `boxList.name.sort()`. It does not work.

```
class Box(object):
   name = “”
   num = 0
   ...
box = Box(name, num)
boxList.append(box)
```

I have a list of box in `boxList`. I want to sort `boxList` alphabetically by the `String name` contains in `boxList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom `key` function using the `name` property of your objects:

```
boxList.sort(key = lambda box : box.name)
```

Alternatively, you can use `operator.itemgetter` instead of a `lambda` function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
boxList.sort(key = itemgetter('name'))
```